# What is the easiest way to sum xml nodes based on multiple related nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to sum a list of values based on related information in the node. The related information is a combination of two pieces of information (below listed as IDa and IDb).

I have an example input like this:

```
<root>
 <node> 
  <IDa>SG</IDa>
  <IDb>01</IDb>
  <value>4</value>
 </node>
 <node>
  <IDa>SG</IDa>
  <IDb>01</IDb>
  <value>2</value>
 </node>
 <node>
  <IDa>SG</IDa>
  <IDb>02</IDb>
  <value>3</value>
 </node>
 <node>
  <IDa>BA</IDa>
  <IDb>01</IDb>
  <value>1</value>
 </node>
 <node>
  <IDa>BA</IDa>
  <IDb>01</IDb>
  <value>4</value>
 </node>
</root>
```

I'm trying to get an output like this:

SG01  4

SG01  2

TOTAL 6

SG02  3

TOTAL 3

BA01  1

BA01  4

TOTAL 5

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using XSLT 3.0 and `for-each-group` with a `composite` grouping key:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node" composite="yes" group-by="IDa, IDb">
        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()!(IDa || ' ' || IDb || ': ' || value), 'Total: ' || sum(current-group()/value)" separator="&#10;"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```